# Bag of words after tokenization

Tags: python, text-mining, text-classification

I have examined many text mining approaches and got stuck while creating bag of words. I understand the point that this is to convert words to numbers so machine could understand it, but the issue is that I have just finished tokenizing, removing stop words, lemmatizing. And ended with a list of words like:

```
['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
```

Basically I decided to tokenize **by words**. Some words are repeated, not distinct. Each bag of words example I read has at the beginning has array of sentences rather that array of words:

```
['Tom likes blue.', 'Adam likes yellow.' ,'Ann likes red and blue']
```

Is my approach correct? Does it make sense to prepare bag of words if I have an array of single words? Or is my tokenization wrong? Or maybe the order is wrong? But in some examples (like here: https://medium.com/@bedigunjit/simple-guide-to-text-classification-nlp-using-svm-and-naive-bayes-with-python-421db3a72d34) we usually tokenize texts at the beginning.

This is supposed to be part of text classification and preparation for using algorithms like Naive Bayes, SVM etc. but I'm stuck at this point... Maybe I got it wrong and bag of words should be created from all my occurrences not just one document?

Comment: Yes, you should tokenize by words. BUT in the example you have shown above, that list is made using tokenizing by character. Please recheck your code of tokenizing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to prepare bag of words from just one tokenized text document which is wrong approach. After you preprocessed each document - corpus - you basically must **go back to to the form of "sentence"** so let's say your tokenized words are:

```
['hello', 'like', mountain', 'spring']
```

just make it

```
'hello like mountain spring'
```

Do it with all documents so you will have array similar to the one from example

```
['hello like mountain summer', 'another string here', 'another also here']
```

And this is the form we can start preparing bag of words, here it will be:

```
{hello, like, mountain, summer, another, string, here, also}
```

And from this point it will be quite easy to count TF, TFID, and this is the form that fit_transform from CountVectorizer expects.

Answer (score -2):

If you share the pipeline there will be a better update. But with your example it is pretty straightforward -

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vec = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
op = vec.fit_transform(['Tom likes blue.', 'Adam likes yellow.' ,'Ann likes red and blue'])
print(op.todense())
print(vec.vocabulary_)
```

**Output**

```
[[0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]]
{'tom': 6, 'likes': 4, 'blue': 3, 'adam': 0, 'yellow': 7, 'ann': 2, 'red': 5, 'and': 1}
```